# DB2 - Foreign key constraint length generated by juplo/hibernate4-maven-plugin is too long

Tags: hibernate, maven, db2, maven-plugin, ddl

I get the error below:

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0107N  The name "FK_11CCTW7HP8CNTIYTKPMYGNBF" is too long.  The maximum
length is "18".  SQLSTATE=42622
```

when i run:

```
db2 'alter table adviserMediaContent add constraint FK_11cctw7hp8cntiytkpmygnbf foreign key (mediaContentId) references mediaContent;'
```

Sql is part of schema generated by juplo/hibernate4-maven-plugin.
Any idea how to shorten the constraint in the plugin?

Comment: You must be running a really old version; the 18 byte restriction on most object names was lifted I think in DB2 9.5 (if you are using DB2 for LUW).

Answer (score 2):

Such names are generated by Hibernate. You can specify a constraint name with a `@ForeginKey` annotation (not JPA, but a Hibernate annotation).

In Hibernate 5 you can use a naming strategy to generate constraint names.